# Is it possible to tell if a brake rotor can be turned without knowing the brand?

Tags: brake-rotor

I need my front brake rotors turned or replaced on my 2011 VW Jetta. I've got them off the car, and I was thinking there would be a marking on them to indicate a brand or a minimum thickness, but there doesn't seem to be anything but manufacturing information stamped on it. The lettering is lightly dot-matrix punched into the middle of the rotor and the only word I can make out is "Mexico." The car is new to me and I don't have any maintenance records that would show what kind of rotors these are.

The rotor surfaces are clean and in good condition, but I think the rotors are warped since the brakes "pulse" when I brake.

Is there a way to tell if these can be turned?

Comment: Once warped I replace them, even if machined they will warp again.

Answer (score 1):

The rotors have a minimum thickness that must be exceeded - usually stated in the workshop manual. So if the rotor will still exceed the minimum thickness after turning then they can be safe to use.

However, if there is evidence of other failures such as cracks developing then that can also mean replacement.

The other issue that can be measured is warping which also means replacement.